# Filter for a Vacuum Pump

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum

We are carrying out some experiments where we pull a vacuum in a chamber but there are some very fine glass beads of diameter between 0.1 and 0.2 mm in the chamber which we don't wish to get into the pump.

Is there some easy to make filter which you have which could be put over the tube feeding into the pump which lets the air through but filters out the glass beads?

Comment: How low (well, or high - one of those confusing things about vacuum) a vacuum are you trying to achieve? If you want a few Torr, perhaps doable. If you want a nanoTorr, can't happen...

Comment: You might use a roughing pump and a pump for low pressure if you wanted nanoTorr. You could put a filter between the two to protect the roughing pump. Perhaps glass wouldn't bother a turbo pump or a cold trap? Or you could put a valve in front of the pump. Crack the valve when starting to pump down. When the pressure has dropped enough where air currents would not stir up dust, open it wider. Close the valve when venting. Be careful because a mistake would mess up your pump.

Comment: Try glass wool or ceramic wool as a filter. You might have to clean it. You might have to try it see how effective it is.

Comment: With glass being heavier than air, a U shaped trap should catch the glass as long as the trap at the bottom of the U  is of sufficient size and air flow is not too fast / turbulent.

Comment: @AdrianHoward - it would not surprise me if some of the glass beads in vacuum moved around just through getting some charge on them. But a cryo would be the pump of choice over a turbo.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe a bottle with in and out is probably the easiest, so the in hole is lower than the out hold and the grains collect on the bottom of the bottle, what would be the easiest way of making this?